# Cannot create a new controller for my new project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

So I'm trying to start up a new project following a tutorial.

I'm using visual studio and writing in .net core.

When I try to create a controller i get the following error:

> There was an error running the template
>   C:\Users\dyl.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\2.1.0\Templates\ControllerGenerator\EmptyController.cshtml:
>   Template Processing Failed:(4,47): error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This may be a newbie question but I can't seem to find the cause of this problem.

---

I've tried separately installing the microsoft.aspnetcore.razor package to my project (which is now installed). But that didn't help.
[image]

If there is some information missing, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is assembly `Razor` version is for `Asp.net Core 2.1` not 2.0, this goes for `Design`, `SqlServer` and `Web.CodeGeneration.Utils` Anything that was marked version 2.1.  Either complete the migration from 2.0 to 2.1 or downgrade those 5 assemblies back to Asp.net Core 2.0

Or start over targeting 2.1 with the drop down at the top of the dialog for project creation

Comment: Thank you! I had to install the new .net core 2.1, then upgrade the target framework in .csproj to netcoreapp2.1 (from netcoreapp2.0) and update the asp.net core 2.0 package. Now it works.